# How to get the value of an attribute in an enum?

Tags: java, enums

So I have this enum...

```
public enum Card {

ACE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10), KING(10);

private int value;

private Card(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

static int getCardValue(Card someCard)
{
    return someCard.getValue();
}

int getValue()
{
    return Card.values()[someCard];
}
```

The isue is that I need to be able to call

```
getCardValue(card);
```

and have it return the value of a card, like 5. I have tried multiple things already to no avail. This is for school, and the getCardValue method has to be exactly as it is now; the only thing I can change is what is inside of getValue. So I need help figuring out what to put in

```
int getValue()
{
return Card.values()[someCard];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `Card.values()[someCard]` to `this.value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think simple!

```
int getValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

---

The `value` refers to the field

```
private int value;
```

which is being set in constructor:

```
private Card(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

The constructor is invoked for every enum literal. This is where you ultimately define the values:

```
ACE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), ...
```